# How do I check if a given argument is the substring of another given argument

Tags: c, arguments

In C programming, passing in arguments is done with

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    // code
}
```

I know argc counts how many arguments there are and argv is where these arguments are stored in a `char*` array. I need help with coming up with an algorithm that can find if a given argument is the substring of a future argument, but these arguments that are passed doesn't necessarily have to be strings.

For example, if this file is called `main` and I input `main lo 17 flow 18 19 flower`, then the output should be something like:

`lo is substring of flow
 lo is substring of flower
 flow is substring of flower`

I'm just starting to learn c programming on my own so I'm having a hard time manipulating the arguments in `char*` argv. Is `char*` argv an array that stores arrays? Like given the above example, `flow` is at index three of the array, but `flow` itself is an array of `char`, so letter 'f' is at index 0? How do I find if one argument is the substring of another later argument?

Comment: look up `strstr` C library function

Comment: There are standard C functions to see if a string is inside another string, see e.g. [this character and string function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) and you should find it. For the rest, loops. And remember that you can have a loop inside another loop.

Comment: Remember, the arguments that are passed *are* necessarily strings.  In particular, the string "17" is a string that is not equivalent to the integer 17.

Comment: In C, strings are character arrays `char *`. If you have a string `char * str`, `str` actually points to the first character in the string. `char **argv` is an array of strings where each entry in `argv` is a pointer to the first character of each string.

Comment: Oh and the array of argument strings is all done and initialized once your `main` function starts. Arguments aren't loaded dynamically or on demand or streamed or anything like that. They are all there for you to check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could use `strstr` with `char **argv`:
Suppose `argv[1] = "lo"` and `argv[2] = "flower"`. Then,

```
char *ptr = strstr(argv[2], argv[1]);
printf("%s", ptr);
```

The `printf` statement would print `"lower"`.

```
if (ptr == NULL) {
    /* string was not found */
} else {
    /* string was found */
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use strstr() as a boolean? Like if argv[0] is indeed a substring of argv[1], then return true?

Comment: yes, just test against NULL or just `if (strstr(a,b))`

Comment: Yes, in sorts. You would just check that `ptr` returned by `strstr` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I got it to work. Out of curiosity though because I'm still learning, how can I do this without the strstr() method provided by the c library? I know it includes using lots of for loops to search each char individually and then comparing them, but if these arguments are already arrays stored in arrays, how do I go about accessing those letters?

Comment: @kelp99 Well, in my response for examle, I had `argv[1] = "lo"`. In that case, you would also have `argv[1][0] = 'l'`, `argv[1][1] = 'o'`, and `argv[1][2] = '\0'`. `argv` behaves the same way that a conventional user defined 2D array does. You can loop through the characters of a command line argument `argv[1]` using `argv[1][i]` for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [strstr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to search for one string in another.

Comment: if this was the answer, then the question would be a duplicate.

Comment: So what? If somebody cares enough they can flag the question.